# Do not comment shaerpoint's Lists.asmx service

Tags: sharepoint-2010, office365, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I am trying to fetch the list of file names which are there in my document library of office 365 SharePoint site.

I am using below code to access the `List.asmx` Service using Visual Studio 2010.

```
ServiceReference1.ListsSoapClient ws = new ServiceReference1.ListsSoapClient();
ws.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "sharepoint");            
ws.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
ws.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress("http://XYZ.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/lists.asmx");
XElement li = ws.GetListCollection();
```

This code gives me below error while executing `ws.GetListCollection()` function:

```
The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'.
```

Can anyone help me that? Is there any problem on SharePoint site access permissions or am I missing something in code part or some configuration things?